# Discord.py, there is any method do edit a message send by a webhook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm currently making a suggestion system but I have a problem, I don't know how to edit a message (embed) send by a webhook, here is my code:

```py
async def suggestion(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('...', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
        embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
        embed.add_field(name="Nouvelle suggestion !", value=ctx.message.content.lstrip(f"{prefix}suggest"))
        embed.set_footer(text=f"""{ctx.message.author} • {datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")}""",
                         icon_url=str(ctx.message.author.avatar_url))
        await webhook.send(embed=embed, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

for adding reactions:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 650397901893140481 and message.author.id not in [296687703851008002, 639138362673987584, 632575363830120448]:
        await message.add_reaction("<:yes:710947936372129854>")
        await message.add_reaction("<:neutral:710949706296983603>")
        await message.add_reaction("<:no:710947944823652362>")
```

for editing the message:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(args[0])
    embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
    embed.add_field(name="Nouvelle suggestion !", value=args[1])
    await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user

Comment: The webhook and the bot are two completely unrelated instances. If you want to edit the message the webhook sent, you'll need to edit it via the webhook, and not the bot - as the error message says, you can't edit a message sent by another user.

Comment: yes now I know, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the misinformation in my previous answer.

Webhooks don't have the ability to edit messages - they're only able to send them. This means that if you want to give the illusion that you've edited a message, you'll need to delete the message(s) and re-send them with the new content.

---

**References:**

- [`discord.Webhook()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook)
- [Discord docs - webhook](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook) - Specifically says they're a "low-effort way to post messages to channels in Discord", and nowhere does it talk about being able to edit messages.
- [Discord docs - editing messages](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#edit-message)

Comment: I made a mistake, my code was "message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(args[0])", and not fetch_webhook (who doesn't work).

The first version of your code doesn't change anything because the webhook variable is not used

The second version I have a error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
and the webhook variable is not used again

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this wasn't possible at the time you asked the question but it is now.
So for reference, an example how I do it in Ruby, no Python example available but it will be alike. The most important part is building the json and send it through the API.

```
require 'discordrb/webhooks'

SECONDEN              = ARGV[0] || 3
WEBHOOK_URL           = "your discord webhook url"
WAIT                  = true
client                = Discordrb::Webhooks::Client.new(url: WEBHOOK_URL)
@my_builder           = Discordrb::Webhooks::Builder.new
@my_builder.content   = "test"
@my_builder.username  = 'discordrb' # you can use whatever
message               = client.execute(@my_builder, WAIT).body
message_id            = JSON.parse(message)["id"]
while true
  sleep SECONDEN
  @my_builder.content = Time.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  RestClient.patch("#{WEBHOOK_URL}/messages/#{message_id}", @my_builder.to_json_hash.to_json, content_type: :json)
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made a library. a tool for discord webhooks

it called [disWebhook](https://pypi.org/project/DisWebhook/)

```py
from DisWebhook import Message

url = "url"
# editing an existing message
mymsg = Message(url)
msg = mymsg.edit("Hello, World!")
print(msg)
# delete the message
#msg.delete()
```

EDIT: after researching. in discord.py docs

[discord.Webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook)

you can edit and delete like a normal message.

i didn't test the code but it's looks fine to me

```py
# webhook
from discord import Webhook, AsyncWebhookAdapter
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def foo():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('url-here', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
        mymassge = await webhook.send('Hello World', username='Foo')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await mymessage.edit(content="the new content of the message")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await mymessage.edit(content="going to delete this message after 5")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await mymassge.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible; important is to do a PATCH request instead of a POST request.
Instead of the webhook URL, use: "WEBHOOK_URL/messages/MESSAGE_ID"
Message ID is obtainable from the returned message object received from sending to a webhook, when using the URL "WEBHOOK_URL?wait=true"

It took me a long time to find out, but it was in PHP, maybe it works different for python.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).